# Combine two data frames in R without repeated entries

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, time-series

I have two data frames containing row entries with respective dates. Data frame 1 contains observations collected from 2010 to 2017.

```
   dates       A
 2010-01-01   21
 2010-01-02   27
 2010-01-03   34
...
 2017-12-29   22
 2017-12-30   32
 2017-12-31   25
```

Data frame 2 contains observations collected from 2015 to 2020.

```
  dates        A
 2015-01-01   20
 2015-01-02   29
 2015-01-03   34
...
 2020-12-29   22
 2020-12-30   27
 2020-12-31   32
```

Both the data frames have missing observations for some days. I wish to combine both data frames to fill out missing data and obtain complete time series upto 2020 without any repeated entries. Like the following data frame:

```
   dates       A
 2010-01-01   21
 2010-01-02   27
 2010-01-03   34
 ...
 2020-12-29   22
 2020-12-30   27
 2020-12-31   32
```

Using `merge(df1, df2, by = 'dates')` or `full_join(df1, df2, by = 'dates')` creates duplicate entries or two columns `A.x` and `A.y` which is not expected.

Comment: What happens if a date is present in `df1` as well as `df2` ? Do you `sum` the `A` values ?

Comment: In that case I take average of both values. Alternatively I can also use values from any one of the data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `df1` and `df2`, if there are duplicate dates which are available in both the dataframes `mean` the `A` value and use `complete` to fill the missing dates.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  bind_rows(df2) %>%
  mutate(dates = as.Date(dates)) %>%
  group_by(dates) %>%
  summarise(A = mean(A)) %>%
  complete(dates = seq(min(date), max(date), by = 'day'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `df` is really just two columns, you should be able to `bind_rows`, `group_by`, and `distinct` to remove duplicates.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
   group_by(dates, A) %>%
   distinct(dates)
```

Edit: This will not work if you have data that doesn't agree between the dataframes on a single date.  If you have two records for 1/1/15 and they have different `A` values, those will both be retained.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
dfout <- unique(rbind(df1,df2))
dfout <- dfout[order(dfout$dates),]
```